# Mandrill inline images not showing in Microsoft outlook but shows in gmail

Tags: image, email, mandrill

I have an issue where email images are not displaying in desktop Outlook (v16.*) when sending an email with an imbedded inline image via Mandrill's email service

The following includes an extract of the JSON I'm passing to Mandrill via their API:

> "images": [{
>               "name": "example.jpg",
>               "type_": "image/jpg",
>               "content": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRg
>        }],
>
> "html": "... < img src=\"cid:example.jpg\" />...",

Images are displaying in other email clients such as:

- Gmail web
- Gmail mobile
- Outlook.com

Instead of seeing an image the user is presented as text file in the form of an attachment.

I am getting this issue when submitting the image through Mandrill's API page as well as via coded post.

Any clues about the possible issue or resolution will be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

Seem like the reason for the problem lies in the mime type. Instead of "jpg" the required type is "jpeg".

Seems to work after that.